# Hyperfine Interaction Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-magnetic-resonance, hyperfine-structure

I didn't had any course on hyperfine interactions and now I am having trouble in solving the Anisotropic Hyperfine Hamiltonian. The problem is of matrix dimensions that have to be considered in the hyperfine term.

I have one nucleus of spin $3/2$ and 4 nuclei of spin $1$ and the electron spin is of course $1/2$. So the matrix of nuclear spin $1$ is $3\times 3$ and the matrix of nuclear spin $3/2$ is $4\times4$. How do I write the Hamiltonian in matrix form for this case?

Supplementary Information:
The $Cu^{2+}$ ion in CuPc has electronic spin $S=1/2$ and nuclear spin $I^{Cu} = 3/2$. The nearest neighbor interactions of 4 nitrogen atoms have been considered which has nuclear spin $I^N = 1$.
$H = -\sum_{i} \sum_{\mu = x,y,z} g_\mu B_\mu^i S_\mu^i + \sum_{i,n} \sum_{\mu,\nu = x,y,z} A_{\mu\nu}^{ni}I_\mu^nS_\nu^i + \sum_{i<j} \sum_{\mu = x,y,z}V_{\mu\nu}^{ij}S_\mu^iS_\nu^j$

where Greek letters indicate spatial indices and n enumerates nuclear species, and i and j indicate electronic spins.

Hyperfine Term
$$
\mathbf{S}\cdot \mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{I} = S_xA_{xx}I_x + S_yA_{yy}I_y + S_zA_{zz}I_z,
$$
where $A = \mathrm{diag}(A_{xx}, A_{yy}, A_{zz})$ is the coupling matrix and $\mathbf S = S_x\mathbf i+S_y\mathbf j + S_z\mathbf k$ is the electronic spin and $\mathbf I = I_x\mathbf i+I_y\mathbf j + I_z\mathbf k$ is the nuclear spin. The problem is that the components of the spin vectors are themselves matrices. ($\mathbf i, \mathbf j, \mathbf k$ are Cartesian unit vectors).

In the answer, this Hamiltonian somehow has 72 eigenvalues.

Link to the paper:-
https://drive.google.com/open?id=172gW5yrbReLFvdSXY9XD5ckzysP-PW9Q

Comment: Welcome! This site uses MathJax (LaTeX notation) for maths; see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a tutorial.

Comment: In principle, if you want to solve this problem using the explicit matrix representations, this Hamiltonian would have dimensions 8$\times$8, if we only focus on spin states. This is because what you have there is the tensor product of the dimension 2 electron spin space and dimension 4 nucleus spin space. This will produce at most 8 different eigenvalues. Since you mention 72, I assume you are considering a bigger Hilbert space, perhaps considering some values of orbital angular momentum?

Comment: This is considering the hightest nucleus spin, 3/2. In the case of spin 1, you would only get $2\times3 = 6$ eigenvalues at most.

Comment: @secavara I have added some more information. And in the Hamiltonian there is no orbital angular momentum term.

Comment: Oh ok, this is a lot of new info to digest and changes the context of the question. For instance, I can see that you have a Hamilonian there for an interaction with several atoms and this increases the dimension of your Hilbert space. Originally I was picturing a single nucleus plus an electron.

Comment: Isn't the 4 nitrogen atoms have similar effect. By this I mean, they will just increase the intensity of peaks on EPR spectrum and won't introduce any new peak.

Comment: 06.10.19: Link now dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can figure out from the paper, the interactions that you are considering involve the electronic spins in Cu$^{2+}$ and the nucleus spins of both the Cu$^{2+}$ and other atoms (including Nitrogen atoms). In order to establish the dimension of your actual Hilbert space you would have to specify the number of electron spins you care about in the Cu$^{2+}$ (let's call this $N_{S,\mathrm{Cu}}$) and the number of additional nucleus you care about with their corresponding spin.

Let's say you only care about Nitrogen, ($N_{I,\mathrm{Nitr}}$). Your final dimension would be something like $2^{N_{S,\mathrm{Cu}}} \times  4 \times 3^{N_{I,\mathrm{Nitr}}}$. The factor of 4 comes from the spin of the nucleus of the Cu. If you consider a single electron spin and 2 nitrogen atoms, you would already have a Hilbert space of dimension 72.

Leaving aside this issue, let's build the Hamiltonian. Let's focus on a single term like $S^{(1)}_x I^{(2)}_y$. This would be the product between the component $x$ of the electronic spin 1 and the component $y$ of the nucleus spin 2. What they mean is this $S^{(1)}_x \otimes I^{(2)}_y$. There is an implicit tensor product between the matrices. In this case, you can build the corresponding final matrix operator with the prescription explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). As you see, if you pick one matrix of dimension 2$\times$2 and one of dimension 3$\times$3, you end up with a matrix of dimension 6$\times$6.

But there is a problem in your case which is that you have a huge Hilbert space that is a product of several subspaces and not just 2. This then means than in a given product of two operators you'll have to fill the remaining gaps with identity matrices, being consistent with the order and dimensionality of each subspace.

Let's say you have a single electron spin and 2 Nitrogen atoms. Let's pick the order: Electron Spin $\otimes$ Cu Nucleus Spin $\otimes$ N Nucleus Spin 1 $\otimes$ N Nucleus Spin 2. Then consider the term $S^{(Cu)}_x I^{(2)}_y$, where the 2 indicates the second Nitrogen atom. Following the order, you would have to write it as $S_x \otimes 1_{4 \times 4} \otimes 1_{3 \times 3} \otimes I_y$, where the $1$s are identity matrices. You could compute this following the prescription I linked and it would be a 72 $\times$ 72 matrix. You would have to do this carefully for each term, add them up and then compute the eigenvalues.

Comment: 2) If you can consider a single electron spin for your work then that's fine. It'd work as in the example I discussed. 1) I don't quite understand this question. It is true that in the expression for the Hamiltonian you don't have products between $I^{Cu}$ and other nuclear spins. Nevertheless, you have to include identities from these spaces when they are absent in the total tensor product.

Comment: Your suggestions came to very valuable. I formed the interaction matrix as:- For Cu $A_{xx}^{Cu}*S_x \otimes I_{9\times 9} \otimes I_x^{Cu}$ and for N $A_{xx}^{N}*S_x \otimes I_{12\times 12} \otimes I_x^{N}$. Similarly for other components. This gave me 72 x 72 matrix but only 24 non degenerate eigenvalues.

Comment: Oh nice, but be careful about being consistent with the order. If I understand correctly, I don't agree with the way you wrote the first operator. I would write $A^{Cu}_{xx} S_x \otimes I^{Cu}_{x} \otimes 1_{9 \times 9}$. And then, for the second operator you wrote there, this would be an interaction between the electronic spin and the SECOND nucleus spin. Remember the order: Electron Spin $\otimes$ Cu Nucleus Spin $\otimes$ N Nucleus Spin 1 $\otimes$ N Nucleus Spin 2.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Hamiltonian in Matrix Form]

Just for sake of completion, here I am sharing the matrix form of the above described Hamiltonian. User secavara provided his valuable explanation for it.
(The code is written in matlab and kron function is for taking Kronecker product)